# XCode Core Data sync with iCloud problems with 'CFType'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I've set up Core Data (sqlite) sync with iCloud. Console output also shows the setup to be working by switching

```
Using local storage: 1
```

to

```
Using local storage: 0
```

However, when trying to trigger [managedObjectContext save:&error], I get a huge bunch of errors hinting that I'm trying to save objects which are not allowed:

> -PFUbiquityTransactionLog writeToDiskWithError:andUpdateFilenameInTransactionEntries:: CoreData: Ubiquity:  CoreData: Ubiquity: Error creating data for export: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3851 "Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')}
>   userInfo: {
>       NSDebugDescription = "Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')";
>   }
>    from transaction log: 
>       transactionLogLocation: : /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~xxxx/CoreData/iCloudStore/mobile~4FBCB2AE-5AF7-453A-9A47-6D85E2BD53AF/iCloudStore/uYeDhL76fnW3SP1Xnk7__Vv38lZ~Gwpw4paFQWOWemg=/BA6EB832-768D-477E-AC70-BAA542003066.1.cdt
>       transactionNumber: 3

Local version of Core Data works perfectly without any errors (also restores all entries after I restart the application). It seems that only iCloud sync is affected.

I've tried to reduce the potential error sources by only adding one single ManagedObjectModel of type "project" which has variables of type: NSNumber (mom: Integer16 & Boolean), NSData (mom: Binary Data), NSString (mom: String), NSDate (mom: Date). It also has several 1:m relations.

By simply adding one project to the MOC and trying to save, the warnings above will appear.

Maybe someone can help me?